# CSS fluid row issue

Tags: css, fluid

I have an angular directive that creates a 3-row layout, with a fixed header and footer, where the content should be fluid based on the content in the middle.

It is a really simple widget which simply shows a collection of rows in the content block, where the content block needs a first-load height, and then needs to stretch until a max height is met and then an overflow off hidden should kick in.

I've got the basics in place, but for the love of me, I can't get the content block to stretch the content:

**/* HTML */**

```
<ng:editor data-control="smartobject">
    <div data-type="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div data-type="body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque molestie ante non volutpat finibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur mollis porta ullamcorper. Nunc enim eros, porttitor in lorem id, dictum iaculis orci. Pellentesque sollicitudin euismod sapien vitae pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam velit purus, scelerisque eget faucibus a, scelerisque sed neque. Proin auctor id eros a venenatis. Nam sed ex sit amet nibh convallis auctor. Vivamus nunc massa, lobortis sit amet fringilla ac, efficitur sed dui. Sed sit amet est ut lacus iaculis vulputate a at libero. Sed vel justo at erat bibendum egestas. Curabitur ac tempus nunc.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-type="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</ng:editor>
```

**/* CSS */**

```
ng\:editor {
    border: solid 1px rgb(239, 239, 239);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 315px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
ng\:editor [data-type=header],
ng\:editor [data-type=footer] {
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
ng\:editor [data-type=header] {
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(239, 239, 239);
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ng\:editor [data-type=footer] {
    border-top: solid 1px rgb(239, 239, 239);
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ng\:editor [data-type=body] {
    bottom: 40px;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It is an architectural requirement to use the angular `ng:directive` notation to call the directive, thus the styling directly on it like that, so don't judge.

All I am doing is trying to get the content to stretch the height of the `<p></p>` tag within.

As simple jsFiddle to show what I've done: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/EricTruter/ttp5snm9/)

Answer (score 1):

To stretch the height of the `p` tag try this:

```
ng\:editor [data-type=body] {
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've removed the `position:absolute` and gave `padding` the same size as the header and footer.

Comment: the problem wasn't the `padding`, it was the `position:absolute`

Comment: i saw that, the problem is, I can now not float two columns in the body, but I can get around this using a <table />, i know, don't shoot me. thanks for your answer, it helped me into the right direction.